# Same Popup text is displayed on both Markers OSM 5

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap

I fetched Longitude and Latitude and Car name from the DB and saved it in an array. The array has two indexes (2 cars). I displayed both Markers within a loop and created Popup for both of them but both Popup show the same car name. when i `console.log()` the name of the cars i see both of names, but in the Popup just the second name is being written on both Popups. I am really stucked since days!.

```
<div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
    <div id="popup-content"></div>
</div>
```

```
/* open street map newest version */
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map', // the div id
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({ 
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.35247, 52.520008]),
        zoom: 6,
        minZoom: 3
    })
});
for(var i=0; i < arrayPos.length; i++) {
    var long = arrayPos[i][0]
    var lat = arrayPos[i][1];
    var vehName = arrayPos[i][2];
    // add a marker to the map
    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [
                new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([long, lat]))
                })  
            ]
        })
    });
layer.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
    src: 'https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/0/0c/Hgv.png', //
    scale: 0.4 // set the size of the vehicle on the map
    })
}));
    map.addLayer(layer);
    
    //initialize the popup
    var container = document.getElementById('popup');
    var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');

    var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
        element: container,
        autoPan: true,
        autoPanAnimation: {
            duration: 250
        }
    });
    map.addOverlay(overlay);
    console.log(vehName); // two different car names
    //display the pop with on mouse over event
    map.on('pointermove', function (event) {        
        if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {      
            var coordinate = event.coordinate;
            //simple text written in the popup, values are just of the second index
    
            content.innerHTML = '<b>Im a vehicle: </b><br>'+vehName; //just the second one is getting displayed
            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        }
        else {
            overlay.setPosition(undefined);
        }
    });
}
```

```
/* Map popup */
.ol-popup {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    bottom: 12px;
    left: -50px;
    min-width: 280px;
}
.ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
    top: 100%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.ol-popup:after {
    border-top-color: white;
    border-width: 10px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
.ol-popup:before {
    border-top-color: #cccccc;
    border-width: 11px;
    left: 48px;
    margin-left: -11px;
}
```